# showing button on the view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have one empty view and some actions on the view toolbar. When I click any of the actions, I need to show one button on the view. so we can it is some kind of dynamic rendering on the view.How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a small example on how to create the toolbar, the handler and button in the view... See [so-viewaction.zip](http://rcp-company.com/uploads/demos/so-viewaction.zip). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi nonty..its perfect!!! its working fine now.. thanks a lot.. the mistake I made that I didnt call composite.layout() function. anyways thanks again..